# Getting random users from MongoDB

Tags: mongoose

I wrote the code that is supposed to send an array with 5 random documents from MongoDB collection. But sadly it returns only an empty array. How to fix?

```
    const arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    User.countDocuments().exec(function (err, count) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
      User.findOne().skip(random).exec(
        function (err, result) {
          arr.push(result)
        })
    })
  }
    res.send(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) into an aggregation stage like this:

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 5
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YnqpPl3kVMa)

As docs says:

> Randomly selects the specified number of documents from its input.

And this is exactly what you want.